# How to "unravel" a polar continent (i.e. Antarctica) from azimuthal projection and convert it into equirectangular?

Tags: coordinate-system, azimuth, mercator

I have very recently gotten into cartography and map projection, and I wanted to visualise the map from Avatar: The Last Airbender into a proper equirectangular map.

Here is the map for those unfamiliar, taken from the show's intro. the four labels are just the characters for each nation, therefore they are unimportant.

[image]

It has been confirmed in the series itself that the world is spherical, from Legend of Korra. However, the map below shows the world as if it were on a flat plane, with the north and south poles being projected on an Azimuthal projection while everything else, from the looks of it, on a cylindrical Orthographic projection like the Mercator or the Equirectangular projection.

The poles have been confirmed to be actual poles, not land masses near the poles, also shown in Legend of Korra, therefore confirming that the North and South poles are in fact projected in an Azimuthal projection.

Now, my question is, how do I project polar landmasses onto a cylindrical projection?

How do I turn the poles from Azimuthal projections to equirectangular projection?

I would assume it would be how Antarctica was mapped from its Azimuthal projection onto the now widespread equirectangular one, but I cannot find anything online that would help me deduce how this was one.

I also have G.Projector on my laptop (it does not allow images to be uploaded in the Azimuthal projection).

Comment: Taking a quick look at [another map](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheLastAirbender/comments/29d3wo/did_a_screen_grab_of_united_republic_in_the/) shown in the series, where you can see the lat/lon graticule, it looks conformal and closer to an [Eisenlohr](https://map-projections.net/single-view/eisenlohr) or [August epicycloidal](https://map-projections.net/single-view/august-epicycloidal) projection, and the continent's shapes look very much like those in the intro map.

Comment: Maybe [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/imaginarymaps/comments/83zoka/i_made_a_mathematically_accurate_map_of_the_world/) would interest you. Once you know the projection (which may never have been officially stated, so you'll have to make some educated assumptions), then it could be possible to georeference and reproject the map.